# DataBinding not working properly

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I made a code that after a deserialization populate a `DataGrid` but there is some problem in the population. This is the code that insert the data in the DataGrid:

```
var leagueTable_Object = 
        JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LeagueTable.RootObject>(responseText);

foreach (var classifica in leagueTable_Object.standing)
{
    League_DataGrid.Items.Add(new LeagueTable.Classifica(){
        name = classifica.position + " " + classifica.teamName});
    var name = new DataGridTextColumn();
    name.Binding = new Binding("name");
    League_DataGrid.Columns.Add(name);

    League_DataGrid.Items.Add(new LeagueTable.Classifica(){ 
               points = classifica.points});
    var points = new DataGridTextColumn();
    points.Binding = new Binding("points");
    League_DataGrid.Columns.Add(points);

    League_DataGrid.Items.Add(new LeagueTable.Classifica(){
               playedGames = classifica.playedGames});
    var playedGames = new DataGridTextColumn();
    playedGames.Binding = new Binding("playedGames");
    League_DataGrid.Columns.Add(playedGames);

    League_DataGrid.Items.Add(new LeagueTable.Classifica(){
               goals = classifica.goals });
    var goals = new DataGridTextColumn();
    goals.Binding = new Binding("goals");
    League_DataGrid.Columns.Add(goals);

    League_DataGrid.Items.Add(new LeagueTable.Classifica(){
               goalsAgainst = classifica.goalsAgainst });
    var goalsAgainst = new DataGridTextColumn();
    goalsAgainst.Binding = new Binding("goalsAgainst");
    League_DataGrid.Columns.Add(goalsAgainst);

    League_DataGrid.Items.Add(new LeagueTable.Classifica(){ 
                goalsDifference = classifica.goalDifference });
    var goalsDifference = new DataGridTextColumn();
    goalsDifference.Binding = new Binding("goalsDifference");
    League_DataGrid.Columns.Add(goalsDifference);
}
```

each `DataGrid` in the xaml have this structure:

```
 <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path = 'name'}" 
          Header="Squadra" 
          CanUserResize="true" MinWidth="150" MaxWidth="200"/>
```

and this is the class that contain the structure of the data:

```
public struct Classifica
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public int points { get; set; }
        public int position { get; set; }
        public int playedGames { get; set; }
        public int goals { get; set; }
        public int goalsAgainst { get; set; }
        public int goalsDifference { get; set; }
    }
```

now all the data is insert in the `DataGrid`, but the final result is like this:
[image]

How you can see the data relating to a team are placed on multiple lines and this of course is not good. Furthermore, the data are also included in the columns not specified in the Binding-which is quite strange. Can anyone explain me what am I doing wrong?

#### UPDATE Image with propose solution:

[image]

XAML structure:

[image]

Comment: Why you have ´name.Binding´ six times? I suppose ´name.Binding´,points.Binding´,playedGames.Binding´,goals.Binding´,goalsAgains.Binding´ and goalsDifference.Binding´. In the xaml use <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path = 'name'}",<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path = 'points'}",<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path = 'playedGames'}",<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path = 'goals'}",<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path = 'goalsAgains'}"<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path = 'goalsDifference'}"

Comment: Yeah, is my error after a copy and paster of the first element. I forgot of replace it.

Comment: I already have it in the XAML, see my third image uploaded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looping through every record in your data set and adding the item to the grid once for every column. You only need to add the columns once and the item once.

```
var leagueTable_Object =
    JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LeagueTable.RootObject>(responseText);

DataGridTextColumn name = new DataGridTextColumn();
name.Binding = new Binding("name");
League_DataGrid.Columns.Add(name);

DataGridTextColumn points = new DataGridTextColumn();
points.Binding = new Binding("points");
League_DataGrid.Columns.Add(points);

DataGridTextColumn playedGames = new DataGridTextColumn();
playedGames.Binding = new Binding("playedGames");
League_DataGrid.Columns.Add(playedGames);

DataGridTextColumn goals = new DataGridTextColumn();
goals.Binding = new Binding("goals");
League_DataGrid.Columns.Add(goals);

DataGridTextColumn goalsAgainst = new DataGridTextColumn();
goalsAgainst.Binding = new Binding("goalsAgainst");
League_DataGrid.Columns.Add(goalsAgainst);

DataGridTextColumn goalsDifference = new DataGridTextColumn();
goalsDifference.Binding = new Binding("goalsDifference");
League_DataGrid.Columns.Add(goalsDifference);

foreach (var classifica in leagueTable_Object.standing)
{
    League_DataGrid.Items.Add(new LeagueTable.Classifica
    {
        name = classifica.position + " " + classifica.teamName,
        points = classifica.points,
        playedGames = classifica.playedGames,
        goals = classifica.goals,
        goalsAgainst = classifica.goalsAgainst,
        goalsDifference = classifica.goalDifference
    });

}
```

Also note that this is probably not the best way to bind your data. You would be better off adding the columns to the grid in the Xaml code for example.

## EDIT

After your edit showing your Xaml code, it's now clear you don't need to manually add the columns so instead you only need the code inside the `foreach`. Also, that can be simplified further with some Linq:

```
var leagueTable_Object = 
    JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LeagueTable.RootObject>(responseText);

League_DataGrid.Items.AddRange(
    leagueTable_Object.standing.Select(c => new
    {
        name = c.position + " " + c.teamName,
        points = c.points,
        playedGames = c.playedGames,
        goals = c.goals,
        goalsAgainst = c.goalsAgainst,
        goalsDifference = c.goalDifference
    }));
```

Comment: I've updated the question with an image of your solution.

Comment: @HaroldFinch If you already have your Xaml set up properly, then just remove the lines above the `foreach` as they are not needed.

Comment: Now each team are placed perfect in the DataGrid but there are some column empty and "DifferenzaReti" is repeated in the last one column.. Why happean this?

Comment: Okay, I removed the code above the foreach and all is displayed good there are no value placed in a blank header cell. Just one problem: there is the last one cell empty for each rows, I already set "autogenerate" column to false, what is the problem now?